# How to handle OSS license on GitHub with non-OSS pictures

Tags: licensing, github

I am working on an app that will be open-sourced and published on **GitHub**. But, the problem is, that the graphics my client gives me contains some in-house characters that the company owns. We have a deal that the code will be MIT or Apache 2.0, but how do I handle the images? Do I have to omit their upload on GitHub or can I include two license files? Or what should I do?

Comment: This may be better handled on opensource.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't "pollute" your OSS repo with some proprietary files, its a bit like uploading your OSS code with an Amazon API key or config file with your system's passwords in them.

So you have to find some way to manage the distinction, probably the easiest is to create a new, private, repo for the images or create an archive of them and copy these to the right place as a manual step after getting the OSS source.

Alternatively, put the private images in a different directory, one that is configurable in your app, so you can hold them separately - check out the OSS files and it will reference the special images because they always exist on your system, but not on anyone else who clones the project.

Depending on the app, you might like to deliver some OSS placeholders for these images so anyone who gets your project will not be left with broken image links (assuming they are part of the project and not some config)

Comment: I like the very last one - maybe that is the way to go! Because the problem is that it's an iOS app and If then some enthusiast wants to contribute, the app wouldn't be really runnable without any graphics